# Adding a div to every <span class> (Greasemonkey)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'm about to loose my mind about this simple greasemonkey script

I want to add certain informations to an already existing  with the class .grid_headline

There are 8 Instances of this .grid_headline.
The problem is the loop only adds it to the last instance .grid_headline

```
var allHeader               = document.querySelectorAll(".grid_headline")
var anzahl_container    = document.querySelectorAll(".grid_item")
var new_div                     = document.createElement("div")
var new_div_ma              = document.createElement("div")

//Anzahl Tickets
new_div.classList.add("grid_headline_t");
new_div.innerHTML = 'Anzahl Tickets: '+ anzahl_container.length;

//Anzahl aller Spalten
new_div_ma.classList.add("grid_headline_ma");
new_div_ma.innerHTML = 'Anzahl Mitarbeiter: '+ allHeader.length;


for (var i = 0; i < allHeader.length; i++) {

    allHeader[i].appendChild(new_div);  
    allHeader[i].appendChild(new_div_ma);
}
```

Thanks for every kind of help.

Comment: ***"The problem is the loop only adds it to the last instance .grid_headline"*** Your for loop loops through "allheader" which is defined as all instances of the class grid_headline - therefore allheader.length would be 8; so what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @RachelGallen the problem is that OP only creates one div and that ends at the last header, what OP wants is to have a div for every header, see the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstood the other answer. What was Quentin saying is that an individual `<div>` created by `document.createElement` can only be added into one place. Instead, create the div for every place where you want to add it. That just means move the code that creates the div in the `for` loop:

```
const allHeader = document.querySelectorAll(".grid_headline");
const anzahl_container = document.querySelectorAll(".grid_item");


for (const header of allHeader) {
    const new_div = document.createElement("div");
    const new_div_ma = document.createElement("div");

    //Anzahl Tickets
    new_div.classList.add("grid_headline_t");
    new_div.innerHTML = 'Anzahl Tickets: '+ anzahl_container.length;

    //Anzahl aller Spalten
    new_div_ma.classList.add("grid_headline_ma");
    new_div_ma.innerHTML = 'Anzahl Mitarbeiter: '+ allHeader.length;

    header.appendChild(new_div);  
    header.appendChild(new_div_ma);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks I really missed the obvious. Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

A div can't be in more the one place in the document at the same time.

When you append it to a different element, it is no longer a child of whatever element it was a child of before.

If you want a div inside each span then you need to *create a div* for each span.

---

Aside: HTML forbids div elements being children of span elements. Consider using a different element type.

Comment: Thanks for your input it's no problem to use another element that is not a <div>
But even with another element the results are the same, I really feel I miss something so blatenly obvious.

Comment: @crimvel — Pay attention to the *first* half of the answer. The Aside is less important.